# Некорректно работает GetPixel

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Нужно получить цвет пикселя в определенных координатах окна, использую для этого функцию GetPixel, но в выводе получаю 255 255 255, хотя по координатам явно не белый цвет.

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, "Steam");
HDC DC = GetDC(hwnd);
COLORREF test1;
test1 = GetPixel(DC, 971, 174);
ReleaseDC(hwnd, DC);
cout << (int)GetRValue(test1) << "  " << (int)GetGValue(test1) << "  " << (int)GetBValue(test1) << endl;
```

Окно точно находит и возвращает верный hwnd. Это я проверял.
На других окнах тоже проверял, везде такая же проблема. Может возвращать не 255 255 255, а, например, 12 12 12, при том, что цвет по координатам совсем другой.

Comment: А на мониторах со стандартным значением DPI (96) проверяли?

Comment: "If the pixel is outside of the current clipping region, the return value is CLR_INVALID (0xFFFFFFFF defined in Wingdi.h)." объясняет 255. Про 12 - это уже может быть корректное значение, имхо.

Comment: сделайте перед GetPixel SetPixel - для теста

Comment: Сделал SetPixel. Выводит также 255 255 255)